# Extracting Data from a Multi-Data Column in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm creating a sales leaderboard in HOLISTICS and the column "**user_id**" is a multi-data column.

Here's a snapshot of the column "user_id":

[image]

I need to show the "name" part of the user. I tried using CONVERT and even JSON_VALUE but both are not recognized by Holistics.

I used CAST but still the user_id is in numerical form.

Here's the my code:

[image]

And here's the data output:

[image]

Can you help me on what to do to be able to show the actual name of the sales person?

---

*I'm a newbie here and its my first post that's why all my snipshots are put in a link form.*

Comment: What's holistics?

Comment: Holistics is a flexible business intelligence (BI) automation and visualization software, basically a data analytics platform. It uses SQL to generate reports. We use it in our company to gather data and create reports per department.

Comment: @LalaineDelRosario welcome to SO. Please avoid posting snapshots of code chunks.. always post the code itself.

Comment: @LalaineDelRosario you are using postgres or mysql for the data source ?

Comment: Wow, a JSON value stored in an INT attribute in a relational database - now that's what I call "Multi-data"!

Comment: Please do not post screenshots. use [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Are you saying that Holistics can store json data but cannot access it or that you don't know how to write a report in Holistics using json data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select a particular field from a JSON data (and JSON is what you have in user_id column), try this combination:

```
SELECT 
  JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(user_id,'$.id')) as id
  JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(user_id,'$.name')) as user_name
FROM public.deals
```

This should return the user's id and name from your JSON column.

Whatever software you use, it probably expects the data to be retrieved in a **row-column format**, so you just need to play with the SQL query, so that it returns properly formatted data. And since you have JSONs in a user_id column (which seems weird, but nevermind) - a combination of JSON_EXTRACT, JSON_UNQUOTE and perhaps CAST should do the trick.

But bear in mind, that running `DISTINCT` on a big table using those methods could be slow.